# 1 input field not working correctly all others work fine - Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a very weird bug where 1 input field always returns an empty value even though it is filled with a value.

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('webclix-admin/gebruikers/opslaan')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
    <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Gebruiker Toevoegen</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
            @if(count($errors))
              <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
              @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error}}</li>
              @endforeach
                </ul>
              </div>
            @endif

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gebruikersnaam *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('name')}}" name="name" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('email')}}" name="email" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Wachtwoord *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-10"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Bevestig wachtwoord *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-10"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefoonnummer *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('phone')}}" name="phone" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Voornaam *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('first_name')}}" name="first_name" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Familienaam *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('surname')}}" name="surname" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Geboortedatum</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </span>
                      <input id="date_added" type="text" name="date_of_birth" class="form-control" value="{{old('date_of_birth')}}">
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Straat *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input type="text" value="{{old('street')}}" name="street" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="row">
                          <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Huisnummer + postbus *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" value="{{old('house_number')}}" name="house_number" class="form-control"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Postcode *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" value="{{old('zipcode')}}" name="zipcode" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="row">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stad *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" value="{{old('city')}}" name="city" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="row">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Land *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control m-b" name="country">
                              @foreach($countries as $country)
                                  <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                              @endforeach
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Facturatiegegevens</small></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <div><label class="control-label"> <input type="radio" checked="" value="same" id="billing1" name="billing" {{ old('billing')=="same" ? 'checked='.'"'.'checked'.'"' : '' }}> Gebruik dit adres zowel voor facturatie als voor levering</label></div>
                          <div><label class="control-label"> <input type="radio" value="different" id="billing2" name="billing" {{ old('billing')=="different" ? 'checked='.'"'.'checked'.'"' : '' }}> Factureer op een ander adres</label></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

              <div id="d_billing" style="display:none">

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">BTW-nummer </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('btw_number')}}" name="first_name" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Straat *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input type="text" value="{{old('d_street')}}" name="d_street" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="row">
                          <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Huisnummer + postbus *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" value="{{old('d_house_number')}}" name="d_house_number" class="form-control"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Postcode *</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" value="{{old('d_zipcode')}}" name="d_zipcode" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="row">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stad *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" value="{{old('d_city')}}" name="d_city" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="row">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Land *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control m-b" name="d_country">
                              @foreach($countries as $country)
                                  <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                              @endforeach
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

            </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Voeg Gebruiker toe</button>
                </div>
              </div>

    </div>
    <div class="ibox-footer">
      <p>
        Velden met een * zijn verplicht
      </p>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
    <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Rollen toewijzen</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">

      <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rollen</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" checked disabled>Klant</label>
          @foreach($roles as $role)
            <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="{{$role->id}}" id="Checkbox1"> {{$role->display_name}} </label>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-footer">
      <p>Gebruikers kunnen meerdere rollen hebben. Elke gebruiker heeft standaard de rol van Klant</p>
     </div>
  </div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

When i click submit and i dd() the values i get this:

```
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "email" => "testing@test.com"
    "name" => "Christina testname"
    "password" => "$2y$10$njMYm6uJMxoI4e9n/157vOLPLBBkViUE6uI3I3K8apdkhLnExQs7."
    "first_name" => ""
    "surname" => "Furler"
    "date_of_birth" => "2009-01-14"
    "phone" => "123456798"
  ]
```

**Question**
Only the field `first_name` always returns an empty string . All other input fields work fine. The empty value gets stored in the database , so the controller part is working as intended.

**Extra Code** (UserController where i handle the requests)

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $userRequest, CreateAddressRequest $addressRequest)
    {


      $user = new User([
        'email'         => $userRequest->email,
        'name'          => $userRequest->name,
        'password'      => bcrypt($userRequest->password),
        'first_name'    => $userRequest->first_name,
        'surname'       => $userRequest->surname,
        'date_of_birth' => $userRequest->date_of_birth,
        'phone'         => $userRequest->phone
      ]);
      $user->save();
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the html itself. Can you please post more code?

Comment: which code would you like to see that might be relevant? more html ?

Comment: Let's start with the full html. Including the `<form...` part. And the backend part where you're retrieving the values.

Comment: I posted the full html form. I can post the backend part, but i don't really see how that is necessary because that part is working as intended

Comment: You have a `</small>` tag on line 113 that doesn't have an equivalent opening that(not relevant but I thought i'd point it out so you can fix it). Can you please post a dump of all the POST request? Something like `dd(Input::all())`, or something along those lines. So far I don't see anything wrong with the code itself.

Comment: Aaaa i found the problem. On line 124 you have another field named `first_name`. It's overwriting the first field.

Comment: this line :       <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('btw_number')}}" name="first_name" class="form-control"></div>
          Dupiclate field first_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two text input field with the same name check it out. Might be the cause

```
              <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('first_name')}}" name="first_name" class="form-control"></div>


              <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value="{{old('btw_number')}}" name="first_name" class="form-control"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Christophvh, 

Enjoy coding!